# I want to create a multiple internal link & external link in existing PDF using Java itext 5. How can i do that?

Tags: java, itext, pdf-generation

I want to add internal and external links in existing PDF using Itext5 for my task how can I do that ?

Comment: What have you tried, what stopped you?

Comment: Rectangle linkLocation = new Rectangle(x, y, x + w, y + h);
  PdfDestination destination = new PdfDestination(PdfDestination.FIT);
  PdfAnnotation link = PdfAnnotation.createLink(stamper.getWriter(),linkLocation,
  PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_INVERT, reader.getNumberOfPages(), destination);
  link.setBorder(new PdfBorderArray(0, 0, 0));
  stamper.addAnnotation(link, 2);
  stamper.getOverContent(2).addImage(img); //using this code i'm able to addimg but its redirecting to last page i want it to redirect to brower how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment you wrote

> ```
> Rectangle linkLocation = new Rectangle(x, y, x + w, y + h);
> PdfDestination destination = new PdfDestination(PdfDestination.FIT);
> PdfAnnotation link = PdfAnnotation.createLink(stamper.getWriter(),linkLocation, PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_INVERT, reader.getNumberOfPages(), destination);
> link.setBorder(new PdfBorderArray(0, 0, 0));
> stamper.addAnnotation(link, 2);
> stamper.getOverContent(2).addImage(img);
> ```
>
> using this code i'm able to addimg but its redirecting to last page i want it to redirect to brower how to do that?

In your code you use a `PdfDestination` as target for the link. That kind of target, though, is only *a reference to a location in a PDF file*, see the JavaDocs of that class.

Instead you should use an overload of `PdfAnnotation.createLink` that accepts a `PdfAction`, and use a `PdfAction` you created with a constructor that accepts an `URL` or a `String` containing your target URL.

Comment: PdfAnnotation annotation = PdfAnnotation.createLink(stamper.getWriter(), linkLocation,PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_INVERT, new PdfAction("https://klarifylife.com/"));
I did it like this and it Worked for External Link Redirection Thanks.
How can do for Internal Page redirection in that same PDF ?

Comment: `PdfDestination` has a method `addPage` expecting an indirect reference to the page object in question. You can retrieve that reference from your writer: `PdfIndirectReference ref = writer.getPageReference(page);
        PdfDestination d = new PdfDestination(dest);
        d.addPage(ref);` ... Or you can use the `PdfAnnotation.createLink(PdfWriter, Rectangle, PdfName, int, PdfDestination)` to create such a link annotation.

Comment: So I used PdfAnnotation.createLink() and its worked. But there is one problem since i'm redirecting between multiple pages(eg. there are multiple value in my Header and i'm doing redirection based on Header values) what is happening if I'm at certain page and from there if I'm click on a particular header part(for eg. Student it is redirecting me to student page inside PDF). The cache is is 3 pages the header vlaues position is change and i'm not able to directed from those 3 pages to other part of PDF. So is there anyway to change the position of Rectangle in those 3 pages ?

Comment: I'm afraid I do not quite understand the problem.

Comment: Sorry for that , but I got my solution Thanks.